# Interactive Excel worksheet in PowerPoint

Tags: excel, vba, embed, powerpoint, add-in

I'm wondering if there is a solution to add an interactive Excel worksheet into a PowerPoint slide.  The idea would be to explain a model without having to move to Excel.  The table would not have to update or save, just present the current data. It could even be pasted in.

It might look like:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can embed an Excel object into a PowerPoint slide and edit the Excel cells in PowerPoint when designing the slide, but not when running the presentation.

An open Excel file is just one <kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>Tab</kbd> away. Why make things more complicated than they need to be.

Comment: I guess so. Just trying to avoid leaving the presentation

Comment: Insert the Excel document as an object, then give it an Action Setting of Object Action:  Open or Edit (try both, see which suits your PPT version and tastes best).  Here, either one opens the document in Excel atop the presentation window; no need to bounce out and open Excel or make sure it's open first so you can Alt Tab to it (bows to Ingeborg ... Hiya, ma'am!)

Comment: @SteveRindsberg, Hiya back. You should post that as an answer, so I can upvote it.

Answer (score 0):

Insert the Excel document as an object:

Insert | Object | Create From File and browse to the file you want to insert.

While it's selected, give it an Action Setting:

Insert | Links | Action

In the dialog box that appears, choose Object Action: Open or Edit

Try both, see which suits your PPT version and tastes best. Here, either one opens the document in Excel atop the presentation window; no need to bounce out and open Excel or make sure it's open first.